# create new list for every iteration of for loop

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list of strings I want to append to two different lists. I can't create two separate lists within the for loop

```
Input=["1, 3, 4, 7, 13", "1, 2, 4, 13, 15"]
i=0     
for string in Input:
  list[i]=[]
  list[i].append(string)
  i+=1
```

This is the error I get:
'type' object does not support item assignment

Any advice will be appreciated

Comment: You want one of the strings in a list and the other string in a different list?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  We do not know what result you expect.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Have you tested your current code?  What is the result, and where does it go wrong?

Comment: please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It is not clear at all what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I want one of the strings in a list and the other string in a different list

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the numbers as strings:

```
[i.split(", ") for i in Input]
>> [['1', '3', '4', '7', '13'], ['1', '2', '4', '13', '15']]
```

If you want to change them to integers:

```
[[int(n) for n in i.split(", ")] for i in Input]
>> [[1, 3, 4, 7, 13], [1, 2, 4, 13, 15]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but ideally I'd want them in two separate lists with distinctive names.

Comment: You can just save them into 2 lists using the above code. Like `l1, l2 = [i.split(", ") for i in Input]`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you only want to unpack the list, you can do it likewise:

```
f_list , s_list = Input
```